# Поиск в строке не работает

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Вот фрагмент:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string MainStr = "Word1:Word2:Word3:Word4:Word5";
std::string S = ":";
short X = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MainStr.length(); i++) {
    if (MainStr[i] == S) {
        X = X + 1;
    }
}
```

Почему то пишет ошибку `binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'char' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` В строке с условием.

Что не так?

Comment: Ну про ошибку уже написали, а вот почему бы не воспользоваться методом `find_first_of` для поиска нужного символа?


    size_t pos = 0;
    for(X=0; (pos=MainStr.find_first_of(':', pos)) != string::npos; pos++, X++);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так MainStr - это же не массив, и по нему так просто не пробежаться...
Да и потом, там же char, надо ковычки заменить на одинарные

Comment: Ну может не массив, но ведет себя как массив (это по факту вектор - std::vector)

Comment: И очень даже пробежаться. Причем даже несколькими способами.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `MainStr[i]` имеет тип `char`. Объявляем правильно и радуемся
вместо

```
std::string S = ":";
```

пишем:

```
char S = ':';
```

Comment: А чем отличаются одинарные от двойных?

Comment: Ну так, одинарные для символов, двойные для строк. Внимательнее читайте учебник

Comment: одинарные это один символ типа char, а двойные это константа типа  const char*

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat  - двойка

Comment: @mikillskegg просвети меня двоечника, пожалуйста. в чём я ошибся?

Comment: Двойные - это скорее const char[] или на худой конец `const char*`

Comment: :) нашол к чему придраться :))) p.s. поправил

Comment: 1. Не "ты", а "Вы" 

2. Если такие ошибки допускаешь - значит ничего не понимаешь

3. Не "нашол", а "нашёл". Опять двойка.

И вообще, это строка С, которая представляет собой массив чаров, оканчивающийся символом '\0'

Comment: Генерал @mikillskegg? "Не "ты", а "Вы", "Если такие ошибки допускаешь - значит ничего не понимаешь". Значит, к Вам, барин, "на Вы" надо обращаться?